# getting error "could not load cert with ID "aziot-edged-ca"" while setting up prod certs at IoT Edge Device using azure demo certs

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I am testing to install certs using azure demo certs at the IoT Edge Device as per the steps mentioned "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-manage-device-certificates?view=iotedge-2020-11". But I am facing below error while running iotedge check command

```
× read all preloaded certificates from the Certificates Service - Error
    could not load cert with ID "aziot-edged-ca"
    
    Caused by:
        internal error
    could not load cert with ID "aziot-edged-trust-bundle"
    
    Caused by:
        internal error
    could not load cert with ID "trust-bundle-user"
    
    Caused by:
        internal error
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, this is caused by a file permission error. Make sure that the `iotedge` user has read permissions on the directory and certificates inside.